# Flexible vertical html layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need solve some task in vanilla html+css - bootstrap code for desktop browser-based application. So, I can't use libraries such as jQuery or Ext.

There are container 'wrapper' with three boxes - 'header', 'pane', 'content'. I need the following - wrapper and all three boxes always fit into single screen and take 100% of height/width 
Header is going to be a toolbar and pane is a fixed height box. Content takes the rest of the screen.

I'm unable to make content fit into the rest of page. Can anybody help me ?
Another problem - I need to have testarea in the pane and content. Of course, there are lot's of such contols but I can't use them because this is bootstrap code.

I've created sample page: http://jsfiddle.net/madhollander/6r4nu/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>filterIt</title>
<style>
#wrapper
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
right:0;
bottom:0px;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

#header
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
}
#pane
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
}

#content
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
}
.textbox{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize:none;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>

</head>
<body onload='onload();run();'>
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='header'>
    <button type="button">Apply</button>

    </div>

    <div id='pane'>
        <textarea class="textbox" id="command" wrap="off">command sample</textarea>

    </div>

    <div id='content'>
        <textarea class="textbox" wrap="off" id='log'>log sample</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need javascript/jquery to achive this easily.  Is that an option?

Comment: Also what do you mean by content? is it the div with ID content?

Comment: Contentn is id='content' or #content.

Comment: Pure JavaScript is quite acceptable, looks like textarea will be stretched using JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply using the Flexbox module incorrectly.  Some properties only apply to flex containers, others only apply to flex items.  Also *never* use the old Flexbox properties unless you're also using the modern properties.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/DcesF

```
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#pane {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1;
  flex: 1 1;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.textbox {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to make this 'fluid' layout is to set the `#wrapper` to `height: 100%;`

This stretches it to the body's height (which you should also set to `100%` - as some browsers handle this different from others)

Furthermore, you could set a percentage for each element in height which you can always change to your liking, ofcourse you should set `min-height` rather than `height`, otherwise your elements will overflow and cause layout glitches.

Your page will then look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6r4nu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but here you go anyway:
If you need the three `div`'s to fill the page vertically, you just need to give your wrapper  (and further parent elements) a height of 100%. Then to fill the page, each div gets a height of 33.3%.
like this:

```
#wrapper{
height:100%;
}
#header, #content, #pane{
height:33.3%
}
```

If they shouldn't be equally heigh, just re-calculate the percentage so they add up to 100%.

Comment: You're right, it works. Unfortunately I have to implement a bit different layout.